# Sending Email with spring in a new thread issue

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, email, asynchronous

One of the functionalities of app that I'm developing is that an email is sent every time user get's his invoice registered in our system. Sending an email from Java app easy especially if using Spring framework. I use **JavaMailSenderImpl** and **SimpleMailMessage** from Spring framework and it works okay.

But I need to send email in a new thread so that communication with SMTP server does not slow down the rest of apps processes. Problem is that when I call

```
MailSender.send()
```

method from a new thread, email message is not sent, as opposed when sending in a same thread.
I tried with spring's **@Async annotation, spring Executor and plain old java.lang.Thread** but it doesn't work.

Can email be send asynchronously in java with spring? Had anyone a similar issue with this?
I can post some code samples if needed.

Tnx

Comment: How do you know it's not sent? What do the logs from Spring's classes show?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is never a useful phrase on SO. Tell us what *does* happen, not what doesn't.

Comment: Everything looks ok, no exceptions, no errors reported but the email doesn't arrive. I use gmail as a smtp server for testing.

Comment: is the problem that the mail send routine is not (not asncy) called, or is the problem that the mail does not arrive?

Comment: the problem is that mail does not arrive. same routine for sending mail works and email is sent and received successfully,  but when I put @Async annotation or call it from a new thread it doesnt.. no exceptions or errors of any kind

Comment: @Marko Did you manage to find out what the issue was? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 3):

It should work.

You need to tell Spring that it should pay attention to your `@Async` Annotation by:

```
<task:annotation-driven />
```

And there are some limitations you need to pay respect to:

- the annotated method must belong to a spring bean
- the invocation of the annotated method must be executed from a different Spring Bean (if you are using standard Spring AOP).

Comment: I've put the annotation and both caller and bean containing send method call are spring beans.

Answer (score 3):

1) Add task namespace into spring context. The following xsd is for Spring 3.0 release.
`xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"`

http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd

2) Declare the executor in your spring context file.

```
<!--  Executor for the methods marked wiht @async annotations --> 
<task:executor id="asyncExecutor" pool-size="25" />
```

3) Configure this to Spring task

```
<!--  Configuration for the Runtime --> 
<task:annotation-driven executor="asyncExecutor" />
```

These are all the configuration you need in the Spring context file.

The method you need to perform asynchronously annotate it with @Async annotaion.

Now, all the methods annotated with @async will be handled be spring task executor asynchronously.

Comment: this then requires cglib2 on classpath, when given, cglib complains that some of my controller classes don't offer no-arg constructors... arrgh! but i want constructor injection of dependencies

Answer (score 0):

One of the known issues of executing code in an asynchronous thread is that [the exceptions thrown by that code are lost](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async), unless [you provide a specific handler to catch them](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support-exception). The effect you see (namely, the `@Async` method failing both to properly execute and to show a clue for that failure in the form of a log or stacktrace of some sort) is typically produced by such an exception, indeed thrown but swallowed by the asynchronous thread.

One of the many possible reasons why your `@Async` method works when synchronous is that you are doing some database operation from the method. It works when synchronous, because you are probably calling it from a `@Transactional` method of another `@Service`, so for that thread a `Session` or `EntityManager` is found; but it does not work when asynchronous, because in this case you are on a new thread, and if the `@Async` method is not `@Transactional` itself there is no `Session` or `EntityManager` that could perform the operation.

TL;DR Provide an exception handler to catch exceptions that would be swallowed by the asynchronous thread otherwise, or for the sake of debugging use a big `try`/`catch` for the body of the `@Async` method. You will probably see some exception popping up, then you will need to take the proper actions to avoid it.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. I have digged into the exception message. It sais:
"Unable to relay recipient in non-accepted domain". When sending email synchronously I don't get such an issue and the email is sent properly. The moment I switch into asynchronous approach, it throws such error

Comment: @Przemek I don't think the asynchronicity is to blame per se for that error. Is it possible that, by going asynchronously, some data that e.g. is correctly fetched from a database when the operation is synchronous is otherwise missing?

Comment: I have one transactional method that gets me the email addresses from the DB and then I use the addresses in the method that sends emails. In synchronous version it works, as soon as I switch to asynchronous I get an error as mentioned earlier. This new thread should have an access to the email properties provided in my application.properties, right?

Comment: @Przemek You should check (by logging or the good old System.out.println method) if all the data you need is really there.

Comment: Ok, I have figured out what the problem was, though it was my pure guess. Turns out that the problem was related to smtp connection timeouts. I have added incremented those values:
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=3000
and now it works both synchronously and asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the feature in Spring:

```
@EnableAsync
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```