# Which library of spring should I use to send emails with multy-threading

Tags: multithreading, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I have too many emails. I should write scheduler in order to send messages to them. Messages are different. I use spring framework 4.x.

I can write simple  class, which connects to SMTP server. But in this case I should write my thread library too in order to send emails parallel.

Do spring have already written library which give me more flexible way to do this tasks? I do not want to use threads. It will be nice if spring already have this functionality.

**Do I need Spring integration for this?**

Best regards,

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8755853/4576054

Comment: Do I need spring integration for this too?

Comment: Umm, I guess you don't

Comment: As I know spring integration  does this task automatically.

Comment: Can you not install a local MTA like Postfix and let it handle forwarding the emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you definitely can do that with Spring Integration, because there is an `ExecutorChannel` implementation with can be supplied with an `TaskExecutor` from the Spring Core:

```
<channel id="sendEmailChannel">
   <dispatcher task-executor="threadPoolTaskExecutor"/>
</channel>

<int-mail:outbound-channel-adapter channel="sendEmailChannel" mail-sender="mailSender"/>
```

But anyway you should keep in mind that all Spring Integration components are based on the Java and that `ExecutorService` is used on the background.

From other side if you need only the mail sending stuff from the Spring Integration, it would be an overhead and can simply use Core Spring Framework legacy like `JavaMailSender` as a bean and `@Async` for the `sendMail` method to achieve your `parallel` requirement.

**UPDATE**

> could you tell me whether I need JMS for this situation?

I don't see any JMS-related stuff here. You don't have (or at least don't show) any real `integration` points in your solution. The same I can say even about Spring Integration just for email sending. However with the Spring Boot your SI config will be enough short. From other side if you'll study Spring Integration better eventually you'll get more gain to rely on the Integration components for your systems, as internally, as well as externally with other systems through JMS, AMQP, Kafka etc.

To be honest: a lot of years ago my first acquaintance with Spring Integration was due the requirement to get files from the FTP and have ability to pick up new files automatically. I found the solution only in the Spring Integration `1.0.0.M1`. After that short XML config for the `<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>` I loved Spring Integration and since that time it became as a part of my life. :-)

So, it's up to you to go ahead with Spring Integration in your simple app, or just follow with more formal solution with `JavaMailSender` direct usage.

Comment: thank you for answer! could you tell me whether I need JMS for this situation? I think there is no need to use it , does not it? Also, why spring integration is overhead? Because of too many configuration? Or is there any other reason?

Answer (score 1):

You should use java executors framework. For example you can write something like the code below:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
executor.execute(() -> mailSender.send(mail));
```

Comment: Do I need spring integration for this too?

Comment: No, Executors is a part of JDK.

Comment: my question was another. I was interested If I could do the task without concurrency package of JDK. For instance if spring integration could do that.